# RAM and Flash directories in embedded system based on linux

Tags: linux, boot

There are various directories in linux. Example /root,/var,/etc,/proc,/usr. In embedded system, during boot up, it will copy image from flash to RAM.

Questions:

1. How can i know, which directory goes to RAM and which resides on FLASH?

Comment: Off-topic (not about programming). Also, we don't use signatures (that's what your name card is for).

Comment: You can figure out what file systems are mount where using the mount command, or reading /proc/mounts.  You can look at other data (such as an mtd driver configuration) to figure out what physical storage is backing them.  More complicated schemes are also possible, for example unionfs with a modifiable partition tracking changes in an unmodifiable one.

Comment: About Chris Stratton's comment: You should know that one complete file system is either completely on Flash or completely in RAM. If a file system is mounted R/W then it is definitely in RAM.